# What steps are required to bring haskell-platform up to date?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

I have just installed the `haskell-platform` on my system (Ubunto 12.04 if it matters). I discovered that cabal was still at version 1.14.0.0, and this was causing problems.  I also have some packages (i.e. `regex-base`) that are current but compiled against an ancient version of the MTL library. The is problems resolving dependencies.

Could someone help me out with the steps needed to get the all the pieces of the haskell platform up to date.

Comment: I know you've got some decent rep, but isn't this something for one of the server SE places?

Comment: Haskell isn't exactly a server tool.  It is more of a development tool. There are lot of questions about how to install Python or Ruby, why not Haskell?

Comment: Fair enough, was just asking since if I wanted to update the lang engines on my server, I'd ask in a server SE place.  I obv haven't been around as long as you have, though. :)

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 the [version used](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/haskell-platform) for the `haskell-platform` is 2012.1.0.0. You might want to upgrade your Ubuntu to a more recent version. Otherwise you could install GHC from source and `cabal install` the packages you need.

Comment: I had last year a similar problem on Debian. I added testing to my sourceslist and pinned a newer Haskell version in my apt-preferences. This caused a long chain of updates of packages (newer c-libs implying many other new packages), and now just getting the security updates doesn't work properly anymore. So I cannot recommend this approach.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you have the Haskell Platform, you can absolutely install a newer version of cabal-install (the `cabal` command line program). `cabal install cabal-install` will place the newest version in your **local** cabal binaries directory, i.e. `~/.cabal/bin/cabal`. In order for this to take precedence over the `cabal` that the Platform installed, make sure `~/.cabal/bin` is at the front of your path.

What others have said is correct though. The Haskell Platform is not meant to be a rolling release, and in particular `base` should not be upgraded because it is tied to your version of GHC. If you find you need a newer version of a package, and it's not `base`, just install that one package. If you keep having issues then upgrading Ubuntu to get a newer version of GHC and/or the Platform is recommended.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend getting the latest `cabal-install` to get access to the sandbox and repl functionality; then you can experiment with package versions easily and without fear